# How can I keep elements in the left-hand side in a RichFaces PickList after selection?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I don't want the default behavior which **moves** selected elements from the left to the right side upon pressing the "add" button. I just want to "copy" them to the right, possibly adding elements from the left side more than once to the right side.

see the showcase for a demo:

http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=pickList

I also checked the documentation and API doc, but couldn't find anything like that:

https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/4.5.X/4.5.5.Final/vdldoc/rich/pickList.html

Do you see a way or can recommend an efficient approach to accomplish this behavior?

Comment: Showcase is from RF 4.X, you pasted here docs from RF 3.X, so which is it?

Comment: Sorry, corrected that. But the question remains, the pickList API hasn't been changed significantly.

Comment: Create to custom lists and create some buttons to get the behaviour you need. Way easier than customizing a component this way...